# Android deep link: Skip splash screen if app has already launched/opened

Tags: android, android-deep-link

I would like when users click on a link with below format, they will be given the option to directly launch the app https://www.somedomain.com/asia/country?name=blabla. If the app hasn't launched yet, it should launch the SplashScreenActivity screen; But if the app has already opened, I would like to skip the SplashScreenActivity screen and directly show MainActivity screen.

I configured my manifest as below and set SplashScreenActivity as singleTask, but every time I tap on the deep link url, it launch from start (SplashScreenActivity). Is there any way to work around this?

```
<activity
   android:name=".myapp.ui.SplashScreenActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   android:launchMode="singleTask"
   android:theme="@style/FullScreen">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

       <data
           android:host="www.somedomain.com"
           android:path="/asia/country"
           android:scheme="https"/>

   </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
   android:name=".myapp.ui.MainActivity"
   android:configChanges="layoutDirection|locale"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" >
</activity>
```

Comment: I really dislike if other do not answer my direct question, but still: you should only  display a splash screen, if it is loading data and you can't show something more meaningful in your `MainActiviy`. The fact that you run into your problem tells me a splash screen is not necessary. 

If you still must or want to: `SplashScreenActivity` receives the Intent. In `onCreate` of `SplashScreenActivity`, check for the intent. If it contains a deeplink,  immediately start your MainActivity

Answer (score 1):

Add Intent Filter

```
<activity
    android:name="Your Activity"
    android:label="Your Activity Title"
    android:theme="Your Style">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:host="your url"
            android:path="/your path"
            android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Please explain what this does and how to use it

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the launch mode(singletask) of your SplashActvity then when you SplashActivity will open a method will be called

```
 @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```

use this method to navigate to the MainActivity.

Comment: I tried with onNewIntent() at SplashScreenActivity, but somehow it doesn't get called.